CSS hover move element up, but incompatible with grid
SOLVED: simple answer in comments.
I would like an element defined as such:
<a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-code-branch"></i></a class="gridcomp">

with the css as:
.gridcomp-parent {
   display: grid;
}

to move upwards by 2vh:
.fa-solid:hover {
   top: -2vh;
}

But when I define position as absolute:
.fa-solid {
   position: absolute;
}

it breaks.
What is the correct way to achieve this hover effect when using CSS grid?

look for translate

actually think I figured it out. Would defining my fontawesome as position: relative; get the job done?

ah. yes. translate FTW.
